# Update/Refresh JavaFX Label From MongoDB database (JAVA)

Tags: java, javafx, binding, label, refresh

I'm asking your help because I can't manage to update javaFX Labels with data from my database. 
To be specific, I tried to create a MVC pattern, with a view containing Labels.

I created modules in order to fetch all the data from MongoDB(which are workinf fine). In order to refresh my view, I created in my model a thread which fetch every few second data from the database.
All the data that I collect are stocked in SimpleDoubleProperty/SimpleIntegerProperty/SimpleStringProperty, in order to make biding.

A part of my model class :

```
public SimpleDoubleProperty sto = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0.);
public SimpleIntegerProperty nbA = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
public SimpleStringProperty signalStrengh = new SimpleStringProperty();
public void start() {
    worker = new DataBaseWorker();
    worker.start();
}

private class DataBaseWorker extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        while(!stop) {
            sto.set(MongoDataService.getStorage());
            nbA.set(MongoDataService.getNbAircraft(interval));
            double sig_strengh = MongoDataService.getSignalStrengh(interval);
            if(sig_strengh >= excellent_sig) {
                signalStrengh.set("Excellent");
            }
            else if (sig_strengh> good_sig && sig_strengh <excellent_sig) {
                signalStrengh.set("Good");
            }
            else {
                signalStrengh.set("Poor");
            }

            waitFor(ConfigService.getInstance().getDBFetchDataIntervalInMS());

        }
    }   
}
```

Thereafter, my controller make the bindings (I also tried to make the bindings in my view without success) :

```
    Label data_sto = (Label)((HBox)supervisor.root.getChildren().get(2)).getChildren().get(1);
    Label nbAir_lab = (Label)((HBox)supervisor.root.getChildren().get(3)).getChildren().get(1);
    Label sig_lab = (Label)((HBox)supervisor.root.getChildren().get(4)).getChildren().get(1);
    data_sto.textProperty().bind(model.sto.asString());
    nbAir_lab.textProperty().bind(model.nbA.asString());
    sig_lab.textProperty().bind(model.signalStrengh);
```

Everything compile great and no runtime error. I have my window with everything I created. 
But the issue is that my label are not updated as I expect.

I think the issue may come from the thread I create which doesn't communicate with the binders but because I'm a novice in Java and Javafx it could be anything.

Thank you and I hope that someone will help me.

Comment: [mcve] please .. and stick to java naming conventions ..

Comment: JavaFX applications are designed to run with `Tasks`. https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm